# How to cache "exists" validation in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-validation

I'm trying to cache the db calls for Yii2 exists validation, but can't work out where to initiate it.

Because I'm using a multi-model form with a lot of relations, the overhead is getting a little too much.

Any ideas?

Comment: This is not supported by Yii, you either have to extend the ExistValidator and implement your caching logic there or add a custom ActiveQuery class to your model in question and override the exists() and count() methods

Comment: @Nader I thought as much - just thought I'd ask in case I'd missed something. If you want to add your response as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not supported by Yii, you either have to :

- Extend the `ExistValidator` and implement your caching logic there
- Add a custom `ActiveQuery` class to your model in question and override
  the `exists()` and `count()` methods

Answer (score 3):

You'd better not. Actually, there is [an issue on Yii2 official Github project](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/12125) where one of the framework's core developers, Alexander Makarov aka @samdark, explains why caching `ExistValidator` is a bad idea:

> Exist validation isn't the kind of validation to be cached. Each second database may change its state so it should be validated just before it's saved.

Comment: I agree generally, but this was a specific circumstance in which a tradeoff needed to be made between certainty and performance. Due to the nature of the specific tables in question, the tradeoff was worth the extra performance. I think the general approach is correct, but careful use of an exception to the rule was needed in this case.